# Adding a word after every particular word in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm sorry if my Title seems kinda weird, English is not my first Language and I didn't know how to express myself correctly.

I have a list and I want to add a word every time after a particular word:
Example:

```
list = ['add', 'add', 'ball', 'cup', 'add']
```

Expected result:

```
list = ['add','Nice', 'add', 'Nice, 'ball', 'cup', 'add','Nice']
```

I tried including a:

```
for word in list:
    if 'add' in word:
        list.insert(((list.index(word))+1,'Nice')
```

But my loop keeps adding only on the first 'add', and go eternal.

I tried doing something like this:

```
for word in list:
    if 'add' in word:
        local = list.index(word) + 1
        if list[local] == 'Nice':
            pass
        else:
            list.insert(local,'Nice')
```

It stops the eternal loop, but the second 'add' doesn't get a 'Nice',
I get a: `['add', 'Nice', 'add', 'ball', 'cup', 'add']`

It looks like my "for word in list" only sees a singular 'add'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutating the list you're iterating over easily leads to unexpected results since the internal iterator of the loop has no idea of your modification to the sequence.

Instead, you can create a new list to append output to:

```
lst = ['add', 'add', 'ball', 'cup', 'add']
output = []
for word in lst:
    output.append(word)
    if word == 'add':
        output.append('Nice')
print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
['add', 'Nice', 'add', 'Nice', 'ball', 'cup', 'add', 'Nice']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very shorthand way to do what you want using `sum()` (for short lists)...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

```
words = ['add', 'add', 'ball', 'cup', 'add']

sum(([v,'Nice'] if v == 'add' else [v] for v in words), [])
```

Output is:

```
['add', 'Nice', 'add', 'Nice', 'ball', 'cup', 'add', 'Nice']
```

Also see `itertools.chain()` for longer lists as it is more efficient.